# How to remove the span's text if textbox has text?

Tags: jquery, html

How to remove the span's text if Textbox has text?
I tried below Jquery code which have two conditions i.e, 1 If textbox empty then show span text elese remove the text. but in my code just showing text action is working good but else part not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $('#txtUsername').focusout(function () {
                if ($(this).val().length == '') {
                    $('#tab').text('*All fields are mandatory.');
                    $(this).focus();
                }
                else
                {
                    alert();
                    ('#tab').empty();
                }
            });});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need replace `$(this).val().length == ''` on `if (!$(this).val().length)`, because `.length` always returns number. If you want compare text you can use this `$(this).val() == ''`.

Secondary, you miss `$` in this line `('#tab').empty();`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#txtUsername').focusout(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      $('#tab').text('*All fields are mandatory.');
      $(this).focus();
    } else {
      $('#tab').empty();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="txtUsername">
</textarea>
<div id="tab"></div>
```

Comment: To clarify, the original `$(this).val().length == ''` is "working good[sic]" for OP because, in javascript `0 == ''` so while it's distasteful to compare an int with an empty string, it does work (despite looking wrong).  Conversely, if OP had used `===` then it would not be working and the solution provided here (for that part) would be required as `$(this).val() === ''`